# GZipStream not send when I want

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, stream

I'm trying to use GzipStream over a socket. For this purpose I use something like this.

```
using System.IO.Compression;    
TcpClient _client = null;

// ...
// ... Connection 

NetworkStream networkStream = _client.GetStream();
GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(networkStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
```

when I send a message I use GZipStream methods, Write and Flush:

```
zip.Write (....);
zip.Flush();
```

The problem is that when I run Flush method the message isn't sent. The messages are only sent when I close GZipStream (running Close method of GZipStream class).

I'm trying with this approach:

```
using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(networkStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    zip.Write (....);
}
```

but, when zip class is out of using scope and is disposed (closed), networkStream instance is closed and disposed too.

How can avoid this behaviour? I'm running this in a realtime application and I need to send messages when I want not when GZipStream wants.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I have create a complete snipet.

```
using (var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1514))
{
    var networkStream = client.GetStream();
    client.SendBufferSize = 1;
    client.NoDelay = true;

    using (Stream zip = new GZipStream(networkStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        byte[] dgram = CreateMessage("Testing line 1");
        zip.Write(dgram, 0, dgram.Length);     
    }
    networkStream.Flush();

    // Next using block don't send anything. The server side does't receive anything.  
    // No exception is raised. It seems ok, but anything is sent
    using (Stream zip = new GZipStream(networkStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        byte[] dgram = CreateMessage("Testing line 2");
        {
            zip.Write(dgram, 0, dgram.Length);
        }
    }
    networkStream.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [overload of the `GZipStream` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158301(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a `bool` parameter to say whether to leave the underlying stream open afterwards:

```
using (var zip = new GZipStream(networkStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
{
    zip.Write (....);
}
```

You might want to consider how easily the other end is going to know about the end of the compressed data, however - I don't know whether that's implicit within a gzip stream.

An alternative would be to write to a `MemoryStream` first, and send the (compressed) length and then the compressed data... then the other end could read the length, read that much data, decompress it, and be ready to read the next message afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. But if I run the using block (with your suggestion) twice or more times, only works the first time. Second time no exception is triggered. It seems that works fine but server side doesn't recieve anything.

Comment: @user2499597: That doesn't really give much detail about what happens. You should look at the behaviour using Wireshark to see what's going over the wire. You should also flush the network stream afterwards.

Comment: Flush method doesn't work as we hope with GZipStream.

Comment: @user2499597: I was saying you should flush the *network* stream (after the dispose). And you still need to give more details, basically.

Comment: Thaks for you time @Jon Skeet. I did it wich you told me. Close GZipStream and later Flush NetworkStream but it didn't work fine. What details will be useful to understand this issue? Thank you

Comment: Well more than "it didn't work fine" - what have you observed? Have you looked at the network traffic with Wireshark to determine what's being sent when? What is receiving the data on the other side? If it's your own code, please provide that code...

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have updated the post with a piece of code

Comment: @user2499597: That's still the client code - you still haven't told us *anything* about the server, and you still haven't told us anything about what network traffic you've observed...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`GZipStream` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158301(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a boolean to determine whether to leave the underlying stream open:

> GZipStream Constructor (Stream, CompressionLevel, Boolean)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the GZipStream class by using the specified stream and compression level, and optionally leaves the stream open.

```
using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(networkStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
{
    zip.Write (....);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I run the using block (with your suggestion) twice or more times, only works the first time. Second time no exception is triggered. It seems that works fine but server side doesn't recieve anything.